# Optimizing an average image colour program in haskell using REPA

Tags: python, haskell, optimization, repa

### The problem

I've written a Haskell program that goes through a folder and finds the average colour of each image in the folder. It uses the repa-devil package from hackage to load images into repa arrays. I find the average by adding all the red, blue and green values and then dividing by the number of pixels:

```
-- compiled with -O2
import qualified Data.Array.Repa as R
import Data.Array.Repa.IO.DevIL
import Control.Monad.Trans (liftIO)
import System.Directory (getDirectoryContents)

size :: (R.Source r e) => R.Array r R.DIM3 e -> (Int, Int)
size img = (w, h)
    where (R.Z R.:. h R.:. w R.:. 3) = R.extent img

averageColour :: (R.Source r e, Num e, Integral e) => R.Array r R.DIM3 e -> (Int, Int, Int)
averageColour img = (r `div` n, g `div` n, b `div` n)
    where (w, h)  = size img
          n       = w * h
          (r,g,b) = f 0 0 0 0 0
          f row col r g b
            | row >= w  = f 0 (col + 1) r g b
            | col >= h  = (r, g, b)
            | otherwise = f (row + 1) col (addCol 0 r) (addCol 1 g) (addCol 2 b)
            where addCol x v = v + fromIntegral (img R.! (R.Z R.:. col R.:. row R.:. x))

main :: IO ()
main = do
    files <- fmap (map ("images/olympics_backup/" ++) . filter (`notElem` ["..", "."])) $ getDirectoryContents "images/olympics_backup"
    runIL $ do
        images <- mapM readImage files
        let average = zip (map (\(RGB img) -> averageColour img) images) files
        liftIO . print $ average
```

I have also written this program in Python, using the Python Image Library. It finds the average of the images in the same way:

```
import Image

def get_images(folder):
    images = []
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        images.append(folder + filename)
    return images

def get_average(filename):
    image = Image.open(filename)
    pixels = image.load()
    r = g = b = 0
    for x in xrange(0, image.size[0]):
        for y in xrange(0, image.size[1]):
            colour = pixels[x, y]
            r += colour[0]
            g += colour[1]
            b += colour[2]
    area = image.size[0] * image.size[1]
    r /= area
    g /= area
    b /= area
    return [(r, g, b), filename, image]

def get_colours(images):
    colours = []
    for image in images:
        try:
            colours.append(get_average(image))
        except:
            continue
    return colours

imgs = get_images('images/olympics_backup/')
print get_colours(imgs)
```

When both of these are run on a folder with 301 images the Haskell version is outperformed by 0.2 seconds (0.87 vs 0.64). This seems strange because Haskell is a compiled language (which are often faster than interpreted ones) and I had heard repa arrays had good performance (although this may have just been in comparison to other Haskell data types, like the list).

### What I tried

The first thing I did was notice I was using explicit recursion and so I decided to replace it using a fold, which would also mean I no longer had to check if I was beyond the bounds of the array:

```
(r,g,b) = foldl' f (0,0,0) [(x, y) | x <- [0..w-1], y <- [0..h-1]]
f (r,g,b) (row,col) = (addCol 0 r, addCol 1 g, addCol 2 b)
        where addCol x v = v + fromIntegral (img R.! (R.Z R.:. col R.:. row R.:. x))
```

This made it run slower (1.2 seconds) so I decided to profile the code and see where most of the time was being spent (in case I had created an obvious bottleneck or the repa-devil package was just slow). The profile told me that ~58% of the time was spent in the f function and ~35% of the time was spent in the addCol.

Unfortunately I cannot think of any way to make this run faster. The function is just an array index and an addition - the same as the python code. Is there a way to improve the performance of this code or does the Python Image Library just offer greater performance?

Comment: Using `foldl'` in `(r,g,b) = foldl' f (0,0,0) [(x, y) | x <- [0..w-1], y <- [0..h-1]]` buys you nothing. `foldl'` evaluates the intermediate result to weak head normal form, that is to the `(,,)` constructor here. The components remain thunks. I'm not going to install a package just to check, so I have to guess. Does making `f` strict in `r`, `g` and `b`, `f row col !r !g !b` (requires `BangPatterns` of course) help?

Comment: Using a custom `fold` with repa strikes me as a bad idea that converting to lists might not solve.  I'd bet using `backpermute` to get the color channels as three separate delayed arrays then calling `sumS` would result in better performance if anyone wants to check.

Comment: @DanielFischer making r, g and b strict did help. In fact it made the program a lot slower (17 seconds). Thanks for the suggestion and explanation of foldl' though.

Comment: Don't step outside repa -- converting to lists is a performance killer and negates any benefit you get in repa from fusion or parallelism.

Comment: That's odd. I can see adding the strictness making it a little slower (happens not too rarely), but that much seems suspicious.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry, you were right. I compiled it without -prof and -auto-all and the total time went down to 0.4 seconds (previously I had compiled with -prof -auto-all)

Comment: @matio2matio **Never** do performance measurements with code compiled for profiling if a library using fusion (bytestring, text, vector, repa, others, I'm sure) is involved. Compiling for profiling inhibits a lot of optimisations, and for libraries that depend on them, that is deadly.

Comment: Note, quite a bit of the PIL is written in C. If the Haskell and Python timings are in the same ballpark I'd consider than a good result.

Comment: @matio2matio 301 images of what size? total pixels?

Comment: @leventov 75x75 (5625 pixels). Making the r, g and b strict made it faster than the python

Answer (score 1):

Although the following code is hackish, it is pretty fast.

- Proceeds 75x75 image in 0.03 ms (16 tics / pixel) => approx. 10-20 ms for 300 images
- 512x512 (Lenna) in 1 ms (13.5 tics / pixel)
- 2560x1600 in 12 ms (9.2 tics / pixel)

`yarr` was specially designed to solve the tasks like yours, unfortunately there are some problems (pointed in comments to the code) which don't allow to make the code really succinct and fast simultaneously.

One pixel routine is 3 memory reads + 3 `add`s, so I roughly expect 3 tics / pixel as the limit of this task.

Your can also easily parallelize computation using [`parallel`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parallel-io/0.3.3/doc/html/Control-Concurrent-ParallelIO-Global.html#v%3aparallel) from `parallel-io` package.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, TypeFamilies #-}

import System.Environment

import Data.Yarr
import Data.Yarr.IO.Image
import Data.Yarr.Walk
import Data.Yarr.Utils.FixedVector as V
import Data.Yarr.Shape as S

main :: IO ()
main = do
    [file] <- getArgs
    print =<< getAverage file

getAverage :: FilePath -> IO (Int, Int, Int)
getAverage file = do
    -- Meaningful choice, for homogenious images,
    -- in preference to readRGB(Vectors).
    -- readRGB make the case of representation -> polymorfic access ->
    -- poor performance 
    (RGB imageArr) <- readImage file
    -- let imageArr = readRGBVectors file
    let ext = extent imageArr
    avs <- averageColour imageArr
    return $ V.inspect avs (Fun (,,))


averageColour
    :: (Vector v Int, Dim v ~ N3, Integral e,
        UVecSource r slr l Dim2 v e, PreferredWorkIndex l Dim2 i)
    => UArray r l Dim2 (v e) -> IO (VecList N3 Int)
{-# INLINE averageColour #-}
averageColour image = fmap (V.map (`div` (w * h))) compSums
  where -- `walk (reduce ... (V.zipWith (+))) (return V.zero) image`
        -- would be more idiomatic and theoretically faster,
        -- but had problems with perf too :(
        compSums = walkSlicesSeparate sum (return 0) image
        -- would better to `mapElems fromIntegral imageArr` before counting,
        -- but faced some performance problems and I have no time to dig them
        {-# INLINE sum #-}
        sum = reduceL sumFold (\x y -> x + (fromIntegral y))
        sumFold = S.unrolledFoldl n8 noTouch
        (w, h) = extent image
```

Compile

```
ghc-7.6.1 --make -Odph -rtsopts -threaded -fno-liberate-case -funbox-strict-fields -funfolding-keeness-factor1000 -fllvm -optlo-O3 -fexpose-all-unfoldings -fsimpl-tick-factor=500 -o avc average-color.hs
```